# How to center align some text which is outside and some text which is inside enumerate

Tags: horizontal-alignment

How to center align part A(outside enumeration) and Part B(inside enumeration) ?

```
\documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    Part A
    \end{center}
     \begin{enumerate}
      \item
      \begin{enumerate}
      \item What 
      \item Why 
      \item Write 
      \item Differentiate 
      \begin{center}
     Part B
      \end{center}
      \end{enumerate}
     \end{enumerate}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Why should the `Part B` be centered inside of the `enumerate`?

Comment: its inside a question template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that there are different indents/horizontal spacings in each level of the `enumerate` environment.

One way to center the second `Part B` is to shift back this title to the left margin first and centering then. This involves the calculation of the indent introduced by the first level margin `\leftmargini`, the width of the first level label and the separation of the label and the item text on the first level. `\leftmargini` is defined by LaTeX already, `\labelwidthi` and `\labelsepi` aren't defined.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\newlength{\labelwidthi}
\newlength{\labelsepi}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  Part A
\end{center}
\begin{enumerate}
\setlength{\labelwidthi}{\the\labelwidth}% Store the old widths
\setlength{\labelsepi}{\the\labelsep}%
\item 
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item What 
  \item Why 
  \item Write 
  \item Differentiate 

    \begingroup
    \centering % Remove the indent by leftmargini etc. 
    \hskip-\dimexpr\leftmargini+\labelwidthi+\labelsepi Part B

    \endgroup
  \item Foo
  \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]